# A Function that converts a number into words PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-function

In my Package I'm trying to write a PL/SQL function which converts numbers into words.

My Function:

```
FUNCTION f_numbertoword(pn_number NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  f_numbertoword VARCHAR2(34);
BEGIN
f_numbertoword := (                      <-- Here the 'Statement Ignored' error is raised
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(pn_number),  <-- Here the PLS-00306 error is raised
                    '0','zero '),
                  '1','one '),
                '2','two '),
              '3','three '),
            '4','four '),
          '5','five '),
        '6','six '),
      '7','seven '),
    '8','eight '),
  '9','nine ');
RETURN f_numbertoword;
END;
```

Which provides me the following errors:

> Error: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'REPLACE'

I don't know how to take care of these errors or do you even suggest a even better and more esthetic function style to achieve the same result. e.g.

```
f_numbertoword(123);
```

Returns:

> 'one two three'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nesting of REPLACE and the parentheses is invalid. Fix it like this:

```
FUNCTION f_numbertoword(pn_number NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  f_numbertoword VARCHAR2(34);
BEGIN
f_numbertoword := REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(pn_number,
                    '0','zero '),
                  '1','one '),
                '2','two '),
              '3','three '),
            '4','four '),
          '5','five '),
        '6','six '),
      '7','seven '),
    '8','eight '),
  '9','nine ');
RETURN f_numbertoword;
END;
```

Comment: Great, Thanks @Codo

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this way as well:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_numbertoword(pn_number NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  f_numbertoword VARCHAR2(500):= null;
  v_len number;
  v_num number;
  v_name varchar2(100);

BEGIN

  v_len:= length(pn_number);

  for i in 1..v_len
  loop
   v_num := substr(pn_number,i,1);

   --dbms_output.put_line(v_num);

  v_name :=  case when (v_num = 0) THEN
                       'zero'
                        when (v_num = 1) THEN
                        'one'
                        when (v_num = 2) THEN
                        'two'
                        when (v_num = 3) THEN
                        'three'
                        when (v_num = 4) THEN
                        'four'
                        when (v_num = 5) THEN
                        'five'
                        when (v_num = 6) THEN
                        'six'
                        when (v_num = 7) THEN
                        'seven'
                        when (v_num = 8) THEN
                        'eight'
                        when (v_num = 9) THEN
                        'nine'
                    end;

   f_numbertoword:=f_numbertoword||' '|| v_name;              

  end loop;              

RETURN f_numbertoword;
END;
```

Output

```
SQL> select f_numbertoword(9) from dual;

F_NUMBERTOWORD(123)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 one two three
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. Per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm), the `REPLACE` function accepts either two or three arguments. On the line on which the PLS-00306 error is raised, you are calling it with one argument.

Comment: Additionally, the outmost expression is `(subexpresion, '9', 'nine'), which doesn't make sense.